# Active Storage + rails not working with docker + nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, docker-compose, rails-activestorage

I am using active storage in rails 6 with Docker and Nginx. I am uploading an image through the rails console, i.e.,

`object.images.attach(io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/image_path"), filename: "image.jpg")`

It is uploading successfully, but the file is not getting stored in the specified location i.e., `Rails.root.join("storage")`. And for that, I am not getting the image files.

I am not sure if the issue is with Docker or Nginx or ActiveStorage

Please help...

- app.Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.0.0
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /app
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb", "-p", "3000"]
```

- nginx.Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils
ENV RAILS_ROOT /app
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
RUN mkdir log
COPY public public/
COPY ./nginx.conf /tmp/docker.nginx
RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

- nginx.conf

```
upstream app {
  server 'app:3000';
}
server {
  listen 3000;
  server_name localhost;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root /app/public;
  access_log /app/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /app/log/nginx.error.log info;
  if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /maintenance.html last;
    break;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
      break;
    }
    if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
    }
    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://app;
      break;
    }
  }
  location ~ ^(?!/rails/).+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|json|txt|xml)$ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    try_files $uri =404;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
  }
  location = /500.html {
    root /app/current/public;
  }
}
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3.29
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE_NAME: database
      MARIADB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - network_name
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app.Dockerfile
    container_name: container_name
    command: bash -c "bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -p 3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
      - bundle-volume:/usr/local/bundle
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - network_name
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - network_name
volumes:
  db-volume:
  bundle-volume:
networks:
  network_name:
```

- config/storage.yml

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Comment: Can you show config/storage.yml?

Comment: I am also being able to fetch the URL of the image, but the file is not there

Comment: I can assume that the `storage` directory is not empty and it contains two-letter subdirectories and files like `zyvah85d4oz9otpswo4cwgotem5r`. If so, then one of these files is yours image.jpg

Comment: The storage directory is empty and also I have removed all the data from tables, Even on fresh image upload, the data in tables are being stored, but no file is being stored in the storage directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a naming convention issue in your docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3.29
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

In volumes, as you have given the folder name `my_app` so files are created for the service `my_app` service, not for `app` service.
So `.:/my_app` should be changed to your application service name i.e `.:/app`. Modify all the volumes and it should work.